# Simple jquery not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is my first time using jquery, and I don't know why this simple section won't work. I have two buttons, one which hides a div and another which shows it, but the buttons keep doing a postback even though I have set the UseSubmitBehaviour to false.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Social_WorkerButton").click((function () {
        $("#SponsorDetails").hide("slow");
    });
    $("#SponsorButton").click(function () {
        $("#SponsorDetails").show("slow");
    });
});
```

this is the script block inside the head, the reference to the jquery file is in the masterpage.

EDIT: I get a warning that the second semicolon should be a , or ) but I don't see why, the code is straight from w3 schools

Comment: When the final page loads in your browser, check if the jquery-x.x.x.js is included in the source code of your page!

Comment: it seems so, the reference IS listed at the top but not the actual code

Comment: check the js console (ctrl+j in Chrome and FF for errors)

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code for the buttons this script targets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the event argument's `preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior from happening (in this case, the button submitting).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Social_WorkerButton").click((function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#SponsorDetails").hide("slow");
    });
    $("#SponsorButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#SponsorDetails").show("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried it, but still doing postback

Comment: Hmm... normally that works. You could also try returning false at the end of each click handler. Are you sure those selectors are finding the buttons correctly? Perhaps place an alert at the top of the handler to see if those handlers are even firing.

Comment: There was an extra parentheses as pointed out by Nix, but I still needed the preventDefault() method to stop postback, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I see you've tagged ASP.NET. You don't happen to use ASP: controls, are you? I don't see a reason to do that, if you are not using them in your code behind. Try using a simple HTML `<input type="button" />` or simply `<button />`.

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Social_WorkerButton").click(function () { // <-- Extra parenteses removed
        $("#SponsorDetails").hide("slow");
    });
    $("#SponsorButton").click(function () {
        $("#SponsorDetails").show("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using asp: buttons, but I also tried it with regular html buttons and the suggestion by the above answer and still didn't work.

Comment: Ok found it, thanks. Also needed the preventDefault() method above, so I'll have to mark that as the chosen answer. thanks again